# set revolute joint start angle

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to know if it's possible to set a start angle which is not 0 directly in the urdf.

By default on our arm, when all the joints are at 0, the arm is pointing down (through the floor if you import it directly in Gazebo, without attaching it to a table). It would be better if I could specify default values for the joint angles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9889/set-revolute-joint-start-angle/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Please take a look at the service call [gazebo/set_model_configuration](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo) in gazebo wiki to set pose of the robot.  The strategy I've tested here is:

- start simulation paused.
- call gazebo/set_model_configuration with list of joint angles
- [if holding position, trigger controller reset to set new goals]
- unpause simulation

Hope this helps.

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsaund](https://answers.ros.org/users/29303/bsaund/) on 2017-02-09**:
You can do this entirely from launch functions, as spawn_model has an "-unpause" option

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a way that works for me. Since there is no such xml/urdf tag for setting default values hence poses, setting the [rpy] in your **origin** tag kinda does the trick for me. Hope it helps someone.

---

Originally posted by [pendragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32929/pendragon/) with karma: 11 on 2017-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeSuisYasu](https://answers.ros.org/users/55275/jesuisyasu/) on 2020-06-16**:
Thanks for this, it partly solved my issues!
However, by editing the origin/rpy element in the joint tag, it messes up the joint range since the 0 position of the joint is now altered. I wish URDF gave us a way to configure initial joint positions... :(